# Only write values to R dataframe and not lists with an element each

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm trying to run the following code to calculate the training and test mses for a list of different dof values(from the mses dataframe). The logic and calculation works fine, except that the values written to the columns of the data frame are lists with a single element each. How can I directly write the values into the dataframe instead of lists.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
mses <- data.frame(dof = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)) %>%
  mutate(train_mse = 0,
         test_mse = 0)

for(row in 1:nrow(mses)) {
    data_prep <- data_train %>%
      recipe(y~x) %>%
      step_ns(x, deg_free = mses[row,]$dof) %>%
      prep()
    train_data_baked <- bake(data_prep, new_data = NULL)
    test_data_baked <- bake(data_prep, new_data = test_data)
    fit <- lm_mod %>% 
      fit(y ~ ., data = train_data_baked)
    data_train_pred <- augment(fit, train_data_baked)
    data_test_pred <- augment(fit, test_data_baked)
    mses[row,]$train_mse <- rmse(data_train_pred, truth = y, estimate = .pred) %>% pull(.estimate)
    mses[row,]$test_mse <- rmse(data_test_pred, truth = y, estimate = .pred) %>% pull(.estimate)
}

mses

dof train_mse test_mse
5   7.86411 7.417473
6   7.799764 7.469411
7   7.774885 7.443789
8   7.652001 7.377031
9   7.224786 6.844998
10  4.369653 4.189723
11  5.614708 5.741194
12  4.388925 4.146042
13  4.137634 3.746277
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `unlist(yourList)` before writing it into the data frame.